# Getting error in compressing bitmap in android

Tags: android

```
File file = new File(imgfilepath);
if(file.exists()&&file.canRead())
{
    try{
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgfilepath);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        error=1;
    }

    try{
        blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        error=2;
    }

    try{
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,1, blob);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        error=3;
    }

    try{
        bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        error=4;
    }
}
```

I get the error value 3 how to solve this problem, the provided image is jpg.
it works for some times but now it will returns the error

Comment: what kind of error handling is that? why don't you even print the stacktrace?

Comment: Can you print a logcat as suggested above. Bitmap.compress does not allow all types of formats of bitmap for instance compression to JPEG only allows opaque pixels bitmaps, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics

Comment: Instead of error=X, do "android.util.Log.d("WTF", "error", e);"